# Can't install php7.2-ldap on Ubuntu 18.10 - "unmet dependencies"

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ldap

Recently I'm working with Laravel and LDAP (Active directory) authentication. But I can't install php7.2-ldap, I also tried to install in php7.3 but failed.

Currently I'm using ubuntu v18.10 with multiple php version.

I tried:
 `$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-ldap`
and got this output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-ldap : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1) but 7.2.20-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried `$ sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` also before do it.

Comment: This may be a question to ask on serverfault or superuser, still some people here are confused between voting to close a question and downvoting everything under a post they consider off-topic. Useful information is useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 7.2.20-1+ubuntu18.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed

`deb.sury.org` refers to Ondřej Surý PPA, you need to reinstall php following these steps :

- You need to have the software-properties-common package installed :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
  ```
- Add the ondrej PPA repo and update sources :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install php and needed extensions :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install php7.2-common php7.2-ldap
  ```

how to : https://pixelspress.com/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/